# How to test ransack output? Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ransack

I`ve got a little problem here and hope you help me. I have a list of hotels in the table.
Here is a view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'List of hotels') %>
<h1>List of hotels</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th><%= sort_link @search, :name, "Name" %></th>
    <th><%= sort_link @search, :breakfast, "Breakfast" %></th>
    <th><%= sort_link @search, :price_for_room, "Price for room" %></th>
    <th><%= sort_link @search, :star_rating, "Star Rating" %></th>
    <th><%= sort_link @search, :average_rating, "Average Rating" %></th>
    <th><%= sort_link @search, :aasm_state, "State" %></th>
  </tr>
  <% @hotels.each do |hotel| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to ""+hotel.name, controller: "hotels", action: "show", id: hotel %></td>
    <td><%= hotel.breakfast %></td>
    <td><%= hotel.price_for_room %></td>
    <td><%= hotel.star_rating %></td>
    <td><%= hotel.average_rating %></td>
    <td><%= hotel.aasm_state %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

And I added ability for users to sort them by name, price etc. Thanks to Ransack gem. But the problem is I have no idea how to test this output. I wrote some tests but I have no idea what to do next. 
spec file:
require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "Admin"  do
    ...

    it { expect(page).to have_link("Name") }
    it { expect(page).to have_link("Breakfast") }
    it { expect(page).to have_link("Price for room") }
    it { expect(page).to have_link("Star Rating") }
    it { expect(page).to have_link("Average Rating") }
    it { expect(page).to have_link("State") }

    ...
```

How do I test sorting and possibly filtering results? Thanks.

> `Rails 4.0.8` `ruby 1.9.3p551` `gem ransack` latest version on this
>   moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A test normally has three phases: setup, execute, assert.

The **setup** phase would be to create some hotels, which have different properties for the aspect you are testing.

The **execute** phase would be to click on the link which sorts the hotels.

The **assert** phase would be to inspect the elements on the page to verify that they're in the correct order.

So you would end up with something like this:

```
# setup (using FactoryGirl or similar)
# note how these are intentionally not sorted
create(:hotel, name: "Hotel C")
create(:hotel, name: "Hotel A")
create(:hotel, name: "Hotel B")

# execute
visit hotels_path
click_link "Name"

# assert
hotel_names = page.all("td.hotel-name").map(&:text)
expect(hotel_names).to eq ["Hotel A", "Hotel B", "Hotel C"]
```